# Regex for splitting up strings (Java)

Tags: java

I have a single string which looks like:

```
6
0 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
4
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0
```

and would like to split into two different strings such as:

```
6
0 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

and the other string being:

```
4
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0
```

Would I do this using regex? Or is there a better way?
note: apart from the 6 and 4 the others numbers will always be 1 or 0.

Comment: How are you getting the string? From a file?

Comment: You could just iterate through the strings line by line and every time you see a string with a single character you could start a new block.

Comment: From a text file, BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))

Comment: Then you can just handle it while you are reading the file, can't you? How are you reading the file anyway?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to read the file contents into a single string first..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to split on newlines, but only when the following character(s) is only digit(s) then a newline.
Try this regex:

```
"\n(?=\\d+\\n)"
```

It uses a [*look ahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert the condition mentioned above.

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "6\n0 1 1 0 0\n1 1 1 1 0\n0 0 0 1 0\n4\n1 1 0 1 0\n0 0 0 1 0\n1 1 0 1 0\n0 1 1 0 0";
    String[] parts = input.split("\n(?=\\d+\\n)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

Output:

```
[6
0 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0, 4
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be possible with regex

Comment: @Bohemian could explain this `("\n(?=\\d+\\n)");` how actually its working.

Comment: @sansix I thought I did. It's the first sentence of my answer expressed as a regex. Read the (added) link in the answer for what a "look ahead" is.

Comment: @Bohemian ohhh my bad, got it now, and +1 for nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do it with regex, as answered by @Bohemian. But only if you're not going to do any other processing on the result. If you're need to parse split strings any further, and if you use regex again, it's gonna make your code too complicated. I'd rather recommend you to send the string to a `java.util.Scanner` and parse the whole string into some more usable data structure or set of classes for future use.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it would require regexp. You can create a `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("([64][^64]+?)", Pattern.MULTILINE)` and create a `java.util.regex.Matcher` out of it and starting find()ing through your CharSequence. You can query for group(1) each time you find() something.

Comment: Regex are a possible solution, but definitely not required in this case. Simple string comparisons could do the same job.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible without regex:

```
String phrase = 
"6
0 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
4
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0";

String delims = "[4 6]+";

String[] parts= phrase.split(delims);
```

Comment: -1 please... this is so lame and doesn't even answer the question